# Download files from public S3 bucket with boto3

Tags: python, boto3

I cannot download a file or even get a listing of the **public** S3 bucket with `boto3`.

The code below works with my own bucket, but not with public one:

```
def s3_list(bucket, s3path_or_prefix):
    bsession = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS['ACCESS_KEY'],
                             aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
                             region_name=settings.AWS['REGION_NAME'])
    s3 = bsession.resource('s3')
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket)
    items = my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=s3path_or_prefix)
    return [ii.key for ii in items]
```

I get an `AccessDenied` error on this code. The bucket is not in my own and I cannot set permissions there, but I am sure it is open to public read.

Comment: What public bucket have you tried so far?

Comment: The code snippet in the question works for me with proper credentials, though you can also directly use `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')` instead of explicitly creating `boto3.Session` object.

Comment: I tried to use 's3://nasanex/MODIS' bucket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the similar issue in the past. I have found a key to this bug in https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/134 .

You can use undocumented trick:

```
import botocore


def s3_list(bucket, s3path_or_prefix, public=False):
    bsession = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS['ACCESS_KEY'],
                             aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
                             region_name=settings.AWS['REGION_NAME'])
    client = bsession.client('s3')
    if public:
        client.meta.events.register('choose-signer.s3.*', botocore.handlers.disable_signing)
    result = client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Delimiter='/', Prefix=s3path_or_prefix)
    return [obj['Prefix'] for obj in result.get('CommonPrefixes')]
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This seems to be the correct solution.

Comment: This is the key change: `client.meta.events.register('choose-signer.s3.*', botocore.handlers.disable_signing)` This works because it means that the requests are not "signed" by the local account, and therefore local credentials are not needed.

Comment: I write a gist: https://gist.github.com/enricofer/21d8975d5ee0487920609f99f0a5ffa7